# MySQL group by with null

Tags: mysql

I have the table "objects":

```
id (int)
name (varchar)
group_id (varchar) default null
```

I do some inserts:

```
insert into objects values(null, 'Cat', null);
insert into objects values(null, 'Dog', null);
insert into objects values(null, 'Mouse', 'AAA');
insert into objects values(null, 'Eagle', 'BBB');
insert into objects values(null, 'Elephant', null);
insert into objects values(null, ' Bull', 'AAA');
```

Then I do a select like this:

```
select * from objects
```

All the rows I inserted show up. However, for those records where the field "group_id" is not null, I just want one to be fetched.
If I run this query:

```
select * from objects group by group_id
```

then only one record with a specific group_id will show up. The problem is that those records that have the group_id set to NULL, will only show up once.
I want all the records to show up apart from those that have the group_id set to something. In that case, only on post has to show up.

I have tried different things, for example using DISTINCT. Distinct works if you only select the specified field. Otherwise it fetches duplicates.
I also tried to group this way:

```
group by id desc, group_id desc
```

In that case the duplicates still show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One conceptually easy way to handle this is to `UNION` together your original query (slightly modified) with a query to obtain all records where the `group_id` is null:

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE group_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY group_id
UNION
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE group_id IS NULL
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13817/1)

By the way, I consider it bad practice to `SELECT` columns in a `GROUP BY` query which are not either aggregates or the column on which the grouping is taking place.  So it is good practice to avoid doing `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`, and this style query may not work in other types of RDBMS.

**Update:**

If you can't use the above query, then you can try this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM objects
GROUP BY COALESECE(group_id, name)
```

This will use the `name` field on all `null` groups.  Of course, this runs the risk that `null` groups with the *same* name will still get aggregated away.

Comment: Than you. Im afraid i cannot use union as the application is quite complex and putting union would require to many changes. I wonder if there is another way to do this without needing to use union.

Comment: Is it really so complex?  What language are you using?

Comment: Im using PHP. The application is HUGE.

Comment: I have an alternative...posting in a couple of minutes.

Comment: this one: select * from objects group by (coalesce(group_id, id)); only fetches onw row per group_id. Do you think it is a good approach? WHen I tried on the real application it seemed to be very slow, even though the fields were indexed..

Comment: This was crashing SQL Fiddle for some reason, but this is along the lines I had in mind.

Comment: Your best bet might be to refactor the PHP code.  If it can't be refactored, then maybe use Stack Overflow careers to find a less toxic place to work.